# outline drawing of text using Emgu

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I want to annotate the camera feed. I am currently using these APIs

```
Image<Bgr, byte>.Draw();
```

However depending on lighting the text is not readable. So I would like to draw the text with a black border and white fill. How do I do this using Emgu?

Answer (score 3):

```
var labeledCameraFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(cameraFrame.Bitmap);

var border = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 40);
labeledCameraFrame.Draw(border, new Bgr(Color.White), -1);
labeledCameraFrame.Draw(border, new Bgr(Color.Black));

CvInvoke.PutText(labeledCameraFrame, "Hello, world", new Point(10, border.Height - 10), FontFace.HersheySimplex, 1.0, new Bgr(Color.Blue).MCvScalar);
```